# Отправка формы методом POST по адресу, указанном в одном из полей, как-то так

Tags: php, javascript, form

Здравствуйте. Сейчас попробую объяснить. Есть форма, которая методом POST отправляет некоторые данные.

```
<form action="/action_X.php" method="post">
<select name="action">
    <option value="action_1">action_1</option>
    <option value="action_2">action_2</option>
</select>
<input name="input_name" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
....
```

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе в select пункта с **action_1**, форма отправлялась по адресу **/action_1.php**, а при выборе **action_2** - соответственно по **/action_2.php**

Можно ли это сделать средствами php, или js, или как-то ещё? Голову сломал) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="/action_X.php" method="post" id="form1">
<select name="action" onchange="changeAction(this)">
    <option value="action_1.php">action_1</option>
    <option value="action_2.php">action_2</option>
</select>
<script>
function changeAction(elm)
{
    document.getElementById('form1').action = elm.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onchange="document.getElementById('form_id').action = '/' + this.value"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. чтобы дополнить ответ, нажмите [edit]